# C program freezes after scanf input

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working on a homework assignment to calculate the nth prime number as chosen by the user. I had this working just fine, and fairly quickly, but I decided to add in an error message if the user put in anything greater than 50000. For some reason, that decided not to work, so I took it out. After that, my program freezes once the user inputs which prime number they want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{   
    long int pFactor,test,nthCount,target,result,notPrime;
    test=2;
    nthCount=0;
    printf("Which prime number do you want to know?");
    scanf("%li",&target);
    while (nthCount<target)
    {   
        for(pFactor=test/2;pFactor>1;pFactor--)
        {
            notPrime=0;
            result=(test%pFactor);
            if(result==0)
            {
                notPrime=1;
                break;
            }
            if(notPrime!=1)
            {   
                nthCount++;
                notPrime=0;
                test++;
            }
        }
    }
    test--;
    printf("The %li prime number is %li.\n",target,test);
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's something scanf related, as anything I try to print after that doesn't come out.

Comment: I don't see any includes in the code you posted. Don't you have some? Have you tried to add print statements that might give indication what the program is actually doing while "freezing"? Have you tried to use a debugger (with breakpoints and so on)?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of an infinite loop?

Comment: Just stdio.h. I must not have copied that, sorry.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I have, and I think that's also a possibility, however, I've put print statements in between the scanf and loop, and those don't come out.

Comment: So if `result==0`, then you break out of the inner loop,but `nthCount` and `target` haven't changed, so your outer `while` loop will spin forever...

Comment: Also, I feel obligated to say: please just avoid using `scanf`.  It is notoriously hard to use.  Prefer using a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf`. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: @jamesdlin, I've read that as well while looking around trying to find a fix to this, however, this is the only read function my professor has taught us at this point.

Comment: @moooeeeep, No, I haven't. I'm using a very, very basic terminal emulator. This is the fourth program I've ever written in the first C class I've ever taken.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(pFactor=test/2;pFactor>1;pFactor--) // where test = 2
```

deduces to, **pFactor>1** is always **false (1>1)**

So, the flow never enters the `for` loop and thus, `nthCount` always remains `0`.

```
while (nthCount<target) // becomes an infinite loop
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realized that yet. I fixed it to be >=, however, I'm still facing the same issue. Nothing after my scanf executes.

Comment: check your logic here:: `result=(test%pFactor);` Here, test = 2, pFactor = 1, so, result = 0 always and thus, you will go to the `if(result==0)` condition and `break` from there. So, again, `while` loop becomes infinite.

Comment: This is exactly the same code I was using previously, or at least the same algorithm. I changed a couple variable names to make more sense, but other than that, the loop function is unaltered. It was working perfectly. I've also tried inserting print statements after the scanf but before the loop, and those aren't printing.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is stuck within an infinite loop. Body of the for loop is unreachable for all cases and that causing the while-loop to run for infinite time. Modify your program and debug your program yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases (program freezes) you can normally quickly get to the root of the problem by making some observations.

First, find out if it's an infinite loop or some function blocking the program flow. 100% CPU usage is a good indicator for an out-of-control loop and 0% CPU usage is a good indicator that your program is blocking, i.e. is waiting for some event to happen. In your case you could have noted that it's the first: an infinite loop.

Then try to find out where and why this happens. You can for example add debug output at strategic positions in suspected loops. You could have adapted your loop body to this:

```
while (nthCount<target)
{   
    /* added debug output: */
    printf("%ld, %ld, %ld\n", target, nthCount, pFactor);
    for(pFactor=test/2;pFactor>1;pFactor--)
    {
        /* omitted for the sake of brevity */
    }
}
```

Running this, you would have seen something like this:

```
$ gcc test.cc && echo 1 | ./a.out | head
Which prime number do you want to know?1
1, 0, 0
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
```

Here you can see that the outer loop is spinning infinitely because the inner loop never executes (the last number is always less or equal to one) and thus the loop condition of the outer loop is never changed (and thus never false). And this is where you can start fixing it.